# No plugin found for prefix 'install'

Tags: maven

I am using Maven 3.2.3. I configure environment variables M2_HOME, JAVA_HOME, Path, but get an error when trying to add a file to my local repository.

`[ERROR] No plugin found for prefix 'install' in the current project and in the p
lugin groups [org.apache.maven.plugins, org.codehaus.mojo] available from the re
positories [local (C:\XXX\Collaboration\maven\repository), central (almrepo.XXX.com/artifactory/XXXRepository), snapshots (almre
po.XXX.com/artifactory/XXXRepository)]'

Solved. I needed to install a security certificate from our Artifactory repository, https://www.almrepo

Comment: What kind of command did you try? Please show the full command you have typed.

Comment: can your artifactory connect to maven central?

Comment: this is the command. mvn install:install-file -Dfile=C:\TEMP\ABCCxfLib.2.0.jar -DgroupId=com.abc.cxf -DartifactId=ABCCxfLib -Dversion=2.0 -Dpackaging=jar

Comment: "can your artifactory connect to maven central" how can I verify this?